# switch_root busybox init problems?

Tags: linux, rootfs

I'm in an embedded linux environment with busybox. I've read through [several](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5032/trouble-getting-busybox-switch-root-to-work) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24083712/launching-linux-from-busybox-pivot-root-or-switch-root-or) trying to learn how to use [switch_root](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman8/switch_root.8.html). I tried this:

```
exec switch_root -c /dev/console /mnt/newroot /bin/busybox init
```

The `switch_root` help prints and I am presented with a new login:

```
[root@buildroot ~]# exec switch_root -c /dev/console /mnt/newroot /bin/busybox init
BusyBox v1.21.0 (2015-04-24 18:14:40 MDT) multi-call binary.
busybox init
Usage: switch_root [-c /dev/console] NEW_ROOT NEW_INIT [ARGS]root /bin/busybox in

Free initramfs and switch to another root fs:
chroot to NEW_ROOT, delete all in /, move NEW_ROOT to /,
execute NEW_INIT. PID must be 1. NEW_ROOT must be a mountpoint.

        -c DEV  Reopen stdio to DEV after switch


Welcome to Buildroot
buildroot login:
```

When I login, **newroot** has not been loaded, old one is still there. Is this because I am running this command directly from command line and not from some kind of init script?

I read in this article and found they perform other steps before running `switch_root`:

```
mount --move /sys /newroot/sys
mount --move /proc /newroot/proc
mount --move /dev /newroot/dev
```

First off, this confuses me. Why would I want to run these commands before running `switch_root`? Does `switch_root` not do this for me?

Anyways, I went ahead and tried running them first and then running my `switch_root` command. However, this hoses things up entirely:

```
[root@buildroot /]# switch_root -c /dev/console /mnt/newroot /bin/busybox init
BusyBox v1.21.0 (2015-04-24 18:14:40 MDT) multi-call binary.

Usage: switch_root [-c /dev/console] NEW_ROOT NEW_INIT [ARGS]

Free initramfs and switch to another root fs:
chroot to NEW_ROOT, delete all in /, move NEW_ROOT to /,
execute NEW_INIT. PID must be 1. NEW_ROOT must be a mountpoint.

        -c DEV  Reopen stdio to DEV after switch

can't open /dev/ttyS0: No such file or directoryole /mnt/newroot /bin/busybox init
can't open /dev/ttyS0: No such file or directory
can't open /dev/ttyS0: No such file or directory
can't open /dev/ttyS0: No such file or directory
can't open /dev/ttyS0: No such file or directory
can't open /dev/ttyS0: No such file or directory
can't open /dev/ttyS0: No such file or directory
... message continues to repeat ...
```

So it looks like because I've moved the mount for dev that when my init runs and trys to put the getty on my serial port it can't find it? Confusion........

Am I missing something fundamental about `switch_root` here? Or some simply command line modifications required?

Answer (score 7):

First, as its helptext says `switch_root` has to be executed as PID 1.
Therefore it needs to be called by an initscript using `exec`.

Second, moving the tmpfilesystems manually is (as you saw) a bad idea.
The error you get is because your console (`/dev/ttyS0`) was moved away with your `mount --move` call.
`switch_root` will delete those mounts automatically.
Therefore your second init (which is called by `switch_root`) needs to mount them again.

Third, here's a short version of the init script I'm using within my initramfs which should help you:

```
#!/bin/sh

ROOT="/mnt/.root"
ROOT_DEV="/dev/sdb2"

echo "init from initramfs"

# mount temporary filesystems
mount -n -t devtmpfs devtmpfs /dev
mount -n -t proc     proc     /proc
mount -n -t sysfs    sysfs    /sys
mount -n -t tmpfs    tmpfs    /run

# mount new root
[ -d ${ROOT} ] || mkdir -p ${ROOT}
mount ${ROOT_DEV} ${ROOT}

# switch to new rootfs and exec init
cd ${ROOT}
exec switch_root . "/sbin/init" "$@"
```

Hope this helps.